# field editor is unusable

Tags: field-editor

What a shame Field editor since EE2.7 is buggy, and it's very difficult to contact the author, no e-mail, no Devot:ee forum support.

It's unusable because always appears this error message when I try using it:

```
This is a Matrix Celltype, it wouldn't take much to make it into a Fieldtype - but why would you with Matrix around?
```

This message appears for any fields (textarea, expresso......) even without Matrix around.

Does someone report the same error??

Comment: I just installed it on an EE 2.7.3 site, and it no longer works. Support is non-existent.

Comment: under EE2.6 it was working fine. What a pity because it manage more easily the channel fields